# Solving a simple matrix differential equation

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, linear-algebra, differential-equations

I want to use Sympy to solve the differential matrix equation: `du/dt = [[0,1],[1,0]]u` with initial value `u(0) = [[4],[2]]`.

The answer is

[image]
[image]

So the complete final answer is: `3e^t[[1],[1]] + e^{-t}[[1],[-1]]`

How could I solve this with SymPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with [dsolve_system](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/ode.html#sympy.solvers.ode.systems.dsolve_system):

Code:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, Function, init_printing
from sympy.solvers.ode.systems import dsolve_system

init_printing()

u1, u2 = symbols("u1 u2", cls=Function)
t = symbols("t")


eqs = [
    Eq(u1(t).diff(t), u2(t)),
    Eq(u2(t).diff(t), u1(t))
]

funcs = [u1(t), u2(t)]
solutions = dsolve_system(eqs, ics={u1(0): 4, u2(0): 2})
solutions[0]
```

Output:

[image]

Output in latex:

```
\left[ u_{1}{\left(t \right)} = 3 e^{t} + e^{- t}, \  u_{2}{\left(t \right)} = 3 e^{t} - e^{- t}\right]
```

**Edit**
For a general matrix, you can write this:

```
import numpy as np

from sympy import symbols, Eq, Function, init_printing
from sympy.solvers.ode.systems import dsolve_system

init_printing()

# Replace with your matrix
A = np.array([
    [0, 1],
    [1, 0]
])
initial_condition = np.array([4, 2])

# Defines the symbols to be used
u = [Function(f'u{i}') for i in range(A.shape[0])]
t = symbols("t")

# Write the expression for the system of differential equations
eqs = []
for i, row in enumerate(A):
    rhs = 0
    for j, coeff in enumerate(row):
        rhs += coeff * u[j](t)

    eqs.append(Eq(u[i](t).diff(t), rhs))

# Solves the system of differential equations
ics = {u[i](0): val for i, val in enumerate(initial_condition)}
solutions = dsolve_system(eqs, ics=ics)

solutions[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to convert the matrix to those equations?  So I could do this with any matrix?

Comment: Not sure, the documentation solves like this

Comment: You could probably create the symbols dynamically with your matrix

Comment: Tried, didn't work :/

Comment: I'm working on this, will post an attempt soon

Comment: @BenG I've edited my response, see if it fits your needs

Comment: ok, i'm going to post mine and review yours for comparison, feedback welcome.  I will mark yours as the answer ultimately for helping me solve

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt for a generic function to solve these kind of equations, based on help from @Joao

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, Function, init_printing
from sympy.solvers.ode.systems import dsolve_system

# Solves du/dt = Au for matrix A, with initial values vector for t=0.
def matrix_differential_eq(A, initial_vals):
    u_n = symbols("u_:" + str(A.cols), cls=Function)
    t = symbols("t")
    u = Matrix([u_n[i](t) for i in range(0, len(u_n))])

    mul = A @ u

    eqs = []
    for i in range (0,len(mul)):
        eqs.append(Eq(u[i].diff(t), mul[i]))

    ics = {}
    for i, val in enumerate(initial_vals):
        ics[u_n[i](0)] = val

    solutions = dsolve_system(eqs, ics=ics)
    return solutions[0]

A = Matrix([[0,1],[1,0]])
initial_vals = Matrix([4,2])
display(matrix_differential_eq(A, initial_vals))
```

Comment: Nice, very organized!